# Mac cursor is jumping and the keyboard and mouse in unresponsive

Tags: macos, boot, mouse, cursor

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8. I have tried rebooting my machine, what else can I try?

(This happened shortly after the latest update but I don't think that is what is causing it).

The input from Mac keyboard and mouse is "jumping". (Took me a while to type this, can hardly type url addresses). When I type the input jumps between forms, often marking my text and deleting it. Sometimes the input is normal though. But mostly the input deletes everything while typing. My cursor is jumping without my control. Neither my mouse is working properly (sometimes working, sometimes not).

What should I do? I have had a similar problem before when I still had support (or perhaps not similar at all, that had to do with my screen freezing). Then the support made me hold down a lot of keys while starting. Think it was something with left and right cmd + shift  simultaniously+s+f+u+l. Holding down this while starting caused a deletion of all. Just bad. I can't find information on this typing combination on the net. Since I would like to try this before handing my computer into expensive repair.

What to do?

Can provide acativity monitor screenshot if thats any help. Now I've done that. It looks pretty normal.

**Update**, **NMDeviceObserver comes up every time I boot** : Lately I have had the "NMDeviceObserver" problem. NMDeviceObserver is unable to shut down. (Don't really know what it does. Havn't installed the damn thing). Til now it hasn't bothered me the least other than an annoying icon (default" pen & pencil).

[NMDeviceObserver, apple support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3003776?start=0&tstart=0)

**A picture, probably not to much help.**

[image]

Comment: Is it [reset of the PRAM](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/26871.html)?

Comment: No thats not it.

Comment: @Wuffers deleted my joke. Well well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I solved it. Turned out to be faulty power supply.

(as mentioned by OP in a flag).